# Using foreach on array in Laravel view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Why is my foreach loop fails with error "Trying to get property of non-object":

```
@foreach ($memberships as $membership)
    {{ $membership->id }}
@endforeach
```

but this works just fine:

```
@foreach ($memberships as $membership)
    <?php print_r($membership['id']); ?>
@endforeach
```

if I `dd($memberships);` I get

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 8
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "id" => 9
  ]
]
```

Comment: The error explanation says enough I think?, its an array, in example 1 you try accessing as object

Comment: Indeed...this works fine:
    `@foreach ($memberships as $membership)
        {{ $membership['id'] }}
    @endforeach`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was pointed out, I was trying to access array as an object...

```
@foreach ($memberships as $membership)
    {{ $membership['id'] }}
@endforeach
```